# how to make tex4ht center a long table as it does with table?

Tags: tables, longtable, tex4ht

when using `\centering` option in `table`, and then using either `tabular` or `longtable` then both come out centered in PDF as expected.

But in tex4ht, only the `tabular` comes out centered in middle of the web page, while the `longtable` is not centered and remained to the left edge of the webpage.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

This is my table

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}\hline
A & B \\\hline
853.075 (sec) & 43.711 (sec)\\\hline
14.218 (minutes) & 0.729 (minutes)\\\hline
\end{tabular}
%\caption{Total real time used to solve all problems}
\end{table}

my table is done

This is my long table

\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|c|}\hline
A & B \\\hline
853.075 (sec) & 43.711 (sec)\\\hline
14.218 (minutes) & 0.729 (minutes)\\\hline
\end{longtable}

my long table is done

\end{document}
```

Compiled using `lualatex foo.tex` shows that both are centered in middle of page

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `make4ht foo.tex "htm"` only the `tabular` is centered:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to make `longtable` be centered as well?

Comment: `\centering` has no effect on a longtable and a longtable inside a table can not do anything useful, so remove the `\begin[table}[H]` and `\centering`.

Comment: but you added `\begin{center}` which also does nothing useful for longtable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, removed `\begin{center}` from long table also. Thaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to fix using bit CSS:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{table.longtable{margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The result:

[image]

I've also updated the `tex4ht` sources.

Comment: Nice fix (working), but now It gets centered always (even if I `\begin{longtable}[l]` or `\begin{longtable}` without specifying the `[c]`).

Comment: Of course, I use this answer for the revert solution. After a quick lookaround at `text4ht` and its 9 contributors, thanks a lot for your contribution #michal.h21.

Comment: @tinmarino thans for your kind words. the table cell alignment is based on the table specifiers by default. to suppress that, you can use something like `\Css{ table.longtable td{text-align:center !important;}}`.